# send facebook application request to friends as a notification or posting on friends wall

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I have developed a facebook app using fbgraph, rails 3 and facebook graph api.
I want to to include few of my facebook friends in the game(app) and when I finish playing the game, I want to send notification to all those friends or want to post on their wall. Important thing is that those friend of mine are not registered to my app. I know many applications do that easily but sadly I am not able to do that. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/5994488/624590 for fetching friends?
Basically along the lines of:

```
facebook_user = FbGraph::User.fetch(user.facebook_identifier, :access_token => user.facebook_access_token)
friends = facebook_user.fetch.friends
```

Also, make sure you have the correct API permissions for retrieving friends lists (should be read_friendlists permission).

Once you have the friends data, use their IDs to get their user objects and target the `feed!` posting statements, for writing on their walls. Be careful not to spam them, though; that wouldn't look good for your app.